# RMI: Is it possible to send a list of dynamically compiled class?

Tags: java, rmi

In my RMI Server, I'm generating .java files then compiling and loading them dynamically. I'm wondering if it is possible to create a bunch of objects from this class and send a list of them to the client.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible? (I mean: what is the problem?)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, however you need to send the code for them first.  Add a method like `compileAndLoad(String)` and it will be able to deserialize/use instances of the class you generated.

Note: this is very insecure, only do this on a trusted network.